# How to implement HTTPS Adapter by IBM Worklight?

Tags: ssl, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm building an Worklight adapter that send HTTPS request to server.

With a web browser like Firefox, I can send request by adding exception but I don't know how to do it in Worklight adapter.

Question: what are steps to implement it?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Changing http to https is simple, you need to update protocol and port elements in adapter's XML file.

But if you're talking about making a request to backend protected by a self-signed certificate you need to implement this - [IBM Worklight Server and self-signed certificates](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fadmin%2Ft_ibm_worklight_server_and_self-signed_certificates.html)