# IBM Worklight encrypt and compact

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-security

The Worklight provides a way to encrypt the data on the Worklight Server in adapter, compress and send to the client? Or do I need encryption manually?

Comment: Please mention the Worklight version you are using when asking questions. You can use HTTPS connection with adapters as well as compressing the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Using HTTPS in Worklight Adapters: [How to implement HTTPS Adapter by IBM Worklight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14453233/how-to-implement-https-adapter-by-ibm-worklight)
2. [Using `compressResponse` in Worklight Adapters](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Client.html).
   Search for "gzip" in the page.

   Basically, in your `invokeProcedure`:

   ```
   {
   adapter : 'adapter-name',
   procedure : 'procedure-name',
   parameters : [],
   compressResponse : true/false
   ```

   }

Comment: Compress are perfect, but the encrypt, the proposed solution with https is applicable  between server-side and clinte-side (Adapter and Mobile)?